# Wanting to return to university, but I have a Master's degree. Funding options?

Tags: funding, united-states, education, changing-fields

My undergraduate is in Biology, I'm a US native.

I'm thinking about going back to school to study a more quantitative discipline like statistics or computer science.

Does anyone know of any scholarship websites, fellowships, or other ways to pay for school expenses?

Right now I'm looking at taking out more loans.  If I work for the government, I'll qualify for their "Public Servant Loan Forgiveness" program which will help.

If anyone has been in my position please let me know how you managed to retrain while not owing your soul to Sallie Mae.  Already having a graduate degree really hurts when it comes to finding financial aid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mention undergrad biology, and then mention graduate degree with no specifics.  can you edit to make it clear?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can add to jakebeal's answer is that, it is generally only true for STEM *research* masters. Most coursework degrees, even in STEM, are not funded. It was unclear from your question whether you were thinking about doing a second masters with a research component, or just looking to get a coursework masters.

That said, if you are looking for a research masters, I agree with jakebeal. However, I don't know of any school or organization that will fund a coursework masters.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., graduate education in a STEM field at a good university is typically funded by the university, not the student.  In addition to your classes, you are expected to "work for your keep" as a research assistant or teaching assistant.  In exchange, your tuition is covered and you are paid a stipend to cover (cheap) living expenses.  Pretty much every Ph.D. program in a STEM field works this way.  If you are only looking for a 2nd Masters' degree, it will depend on the institution.

Answer (score 0):

Even in cases where you're not in a research college, you can sometimes find TA positions, which give you a small stipend and will comp some of your classes. Of course, you would have to show the department that you are capable of handling such classes, both in terms of workload and knowledge of the topic.